# C: Empty parentheses trailing the #define directive name; there's a body to the directive

Tags: c-preprocessor

`#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM2() SET_BIT(DBGMCU->CR, DBGMCU_CR_DBG_TIM2_STOP)`

What is the meaning of `()` here?

Comment: Sorry, I just can't reformat the body of the message. Tried to edit twice, no success.

Comment: Something really weird is happening to formatting. This, at least, looks a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty parameter list in `#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM2()` is
unnecessary but innocuous. It is fairly common practice to define a macro
with an empty parameter list to document the fact that it is a function-like
macro, rather than the definition of a constant.

Comment: Just that? Trailing `()` is equivalent to a space? Do I have to use this macro with `()`? `__HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM2()`?

Comment: In `#define FOO() ...`, the `()` is not equivalent to a space. The macro is
defined with a parameter list of 0 parameters, which is different from *no*
parameter list at all. It means you must invoked the macro as `FOO()`. Invoking
`FOO` will not be recognized.